# How to create basic carousel in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, carousel

I would like to create basic carousel with slide animation. The biggest problem I have is with logic for next and prev buttons' handler.

I am fighting right now how not to slide the whole carousel but only slide in place an element to the next/prev based on clicked button.

Here is what I achived with basic CRA:

https://codesandbox.io/s/yjq2w11k6x

As I said I want to achive a carousel with arrows. On clicking next add first element to array and remove one from the beggining. Also now my whole container is translate. I want to move only pictures. Example of what I want to achieve:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lp602ljjj7

but on the last slide I want to have arrows and be able to show slides from start

Comment: Can you create a working example on codesandbox? If we could see the issues, it would help us diagnose/help further

Comment: I have updated question with codesandbox examples

Comment: I manage to create working now but I don't know how to apply transition for smooth scroll like in an example. Anyone can help?